# Determine CSS-styled Text size in JavaFX / force styling?

Tags: css, text, size, javafx-2

I have a problem determining the width of a rendered text node in JavaFX 2. When using the standard style, everything works fine:

```
Text testText = new Text("test");
double width = testText.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
```

But if I apply custom CSS styling which sets a different font size like this

```
.text-class {
    -fx-font: 20px "Tahoma Bold";
}
```

and apply the CSS class to my example above:

```
Text testText = new Text("test");
testText.getStyleClass().add("text-class");
double width = testText.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
```

I will get the same result as in the first case, so obviously styling is delayed to some later point in time.

How do I determine the width of a CSS-styled text in JavaFX 2? Is it possible to somehow force immediate CSS styling?

Comment: did you try to listen the property testText.layoutBoundsProperty() on changing? I think, there is no way to apply css immidiately, as you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS application is not done immidiately, so, the way to solve the issue, is do your actions, when size of text actually changes.

```
testText.layoutBoundsProperty()
```

Is the property, which responds to bounds, and it stores an immutable object. There are also other properties, telling you about size and position. What you can do - is to attach a change listener on this property, and apply changes, when a modification is done.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works great!
I chose to listen to boundsInParentProperty() though, which seemed to be the right choice after reading http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2009/07/09/javafx12-understanding-bounds
(obviously there is no better documentation for the current JavaFX release).

Answer (score 1):

CSS-Styles are applied on the next so called pulse beside that the layoutBounds are influence by the parent container your put it into.

Comment: OK, thanks for the "pulse" hint - but how do I correctly determine the height of styled text then?

Comment: Without knowing more on why you need the size I'm not sure what I should suggest to you? So what do you need the size for?